# How to Connect Raspberry Pi with GSM sim900a mini rs232

Tags: gsm

I have connected **Raspberry Pi** to **GSM sim900a mini** with the following details:

- convertor max3232 used
- DB9-2 sim900a connected to DB9-3 max3232
- DB9-3 sim900a connected to DB9-2 max3232
- tx (raspberry) connected to tx (max3232)
- rx (raspberry) connected to rx (max3232)

But there's no respond through miniterm.py as I run the command below:

*sudo miniterm.py /dev/ttyAMA0*

I don't Know why the transfer (send/transfer) is not working.

[image: Sim900A]
[image: MAX3232]

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out that I can connect to the Raspberry using the UART interface directly. I was using the rs232.The problem is solved then.

Answer (score 0):

have you set baud rate i think 9600,

I don't have idea about miniterm.py, but try to install minicom.

then minicom -s   for setting all configuration

and then save as default and then go on, I set up is fine..

and also have you enabled uart in your pi??  if no follow www.robot-electronics.co.uk/files/rpi_serial_setup.doc.

Comment: Thank you RahulAN for your reply. Yes the baud rate is 9600. And the uart is enabled.
I have found my problem and will post the answer soon.