# How to connect GSM SIM800L with RaspberryPi?

Tags: gsm, sip

I can find a lot of search results for connecting the [SIM800L](https://www.electrofun.pt/modulo-gprs-gsm-sim800l) with arduinos, quite a few [specs](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-mini-gsm-gprs-cellular-phone-module/downloads), some answers ([1](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55382/how-to-connect-sim800-gsm-add-on-to-raspberrypi-3)), [2](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26458/how-to-connect-raspberry-pi-with-gsm-sim900a-mini-rs232), [3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58858/how-to-connect-rpi-2b-with-sm900)); but what i can't find is how to connect this GSM module to a Raspberry Pi B+ 1.2.

Am i missing something obvious? I'm tinkering with IoT stuff and a fritzing diagram or something would be amazing.

**Edit01**

Well i managed to connect it using the Pi's [GPIO](http://pinout.xyz/) along with some [textual description](http://irishelectronics.ie/SIM800L-V20-5V-Wireless-GSM-GPRS-MODULE) and a [nifty image](http://diyhacking.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/conn.png) for Arduino.

```
SIM800l RPi GPIO
5VIN    2
GND     39
TXD     10
RXD     8`
```

I used this guide to do some basic testing, but either with python or minicom (on 9600 baud, even with AT+IPR=9600) sometimes it looks as though the serial connection just stalls.

I disabled echo (as per a link i lost) and use a 1s delay before sending a command, but it still kinda stalls.

The breakout is the one in the first link and it has two active LEDs:
D6 NET: always blinking
D2 RING: always on
At regular intervals,they'll both turn off for 1-2s.

An antenna is connected (which largely improved the output of `AT+COPS=?`) but the thing can't seem to register.

Periodically I get back

```
+CFUN: 1
+CPIN:READY
Call Ready
SMS Ready`
```

when using minicom (`sudo minicom -o -b 9600 -D /dev/ttyAMA0`). I assume these are UCs but i don't think they'd interfere.

The `/dev/ttyAMA0` line is commented out in `inittab` and this Pi has no `/boot/cmdline.txt` [serial issues](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-serial-port).Also, even after `AT+CREG=2` with a corresponding `OK`, `AT+CREG?` 
The SIM doesn't need a PIN (always `READY`).

I'm out of ideas, i suspect it's some misconfiguration.

Comment: In the end i used a USB dongle, if i ever get it to work maybe i'll reply.

Comment: what USB-dongle did you use?

Comment: @Suncatcher according to my notes, Huawei K3565. HTH

Comment: So you utilized RasPBX?

Comment: Here is a good place to start. https://www.connectedcities.com.ph/blogs/tutorial/sim800l-and-raspberry-pi-3-b-controlled-3-led-tutorial

Comment: [SIM800L GPRS GSM Module w/ Antenna](https://www.ptrobotics.com/hat-placas-de-expansao-raspberry-pi/6519-sim800l-gprs-gsm-module-w-antenna.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work so i used a Huawei K3565 USB dongle instead.

Python code to send the message:

```
command = 'echo "your message here" | gnokii --config .config/gnokii/config --sendsms +351987654321'
output,error  = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

gnokii config file:

```
[global] 
port = /dev/ttyUSB0 
model = AT 
connection = serial 
[connect_script] 
[diconnect_script]
```

YMMV on the /dev, check dmesg.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
SIM800l RPi GPIO
5VIN    2
GND     39
```

suggests that you're powering your GSM modem via your RPi. Don't do that! SIM800 can consume up to 2A during transmission, and your RPi doesn't have extra 2A lying around. Even if your power supply can provide 4.5A, your USB cable, micro USB plug and the over current protection circuit or the RPi are not designed to cope with such currents.

Get a separate power supply for the modem, and only connect GND, TX and RX pins between the RPi and SIM800.

Answer (score 1):

If you periodically get back the info you stated, then maybe you have issues with power supply. Check if it is about 3,7 volt. If is it too low your sim module may restart sometimes. And also check if your power source can provide up to 2 A current.